# HTML local storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am trying to store information on local storage 
after filling the form with data , I want to save the form with its contents in the local storage,  but for some reason it doesn't work once i submit information and refresh the page the information is not saved 
any suggestions

```
<!--local Storage-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function info()
{
    if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined"){
        var fn = document.getElementById("FirstName").value;
        var ln = document.getElementById("LastName").value;
        var zc = document.getElementById("zipcode").value;

        localStorage.FastName = fn;
        localStorage.FirstName = ln;
        localStorage.Zipcode = zc;

        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=localStorage.FastName+" "+" "+localStorage.FirstName+" "+localStorage.Zipcode;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
    }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>fill in your information:</p>
First name: <input type="text" id="FirstName" value=""><br>
Last name: <input type="text" id="LastName" value=""><br>
Zip Code: <input type="text" id="zipcode" value="" >
<p><button onclick="info();" type="button">Submit</button></p>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You probably should use Modernizr to check whether the browser supports localStorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use `localStorage.setItem("FirstName", fn);` to write the values to localStorage.

If you want the values back in the input fields on reload, you need to populate the input fields at application startup by reading back the values from localStorage (via getItem) .

e.g. append at the end

```
<script>
document.getElementById("FirstName").value = localStorage.getItem("FirstName");
...
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Stefan Haustein i also added ReadInfo() function to read the information once i refresh the page. also should i store the information in an array for future functions?